# How do I find the images from the GIF section on Tenor via Selenium + Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I want to find GIFs on Tenor, and download them.

Example: URL : https://tenor.com/search/dance-gifs
I want to download the GIFs section which seem to have this HTML code:

```
<div class="Gif "><img src="https://media.tenor.com/Lbrr3HR3CnkAAAAM/snoop-dogg-rap.gif" width="290" height="460.0454545454545" alt="Snoop Dogg Rap GIF - Snoop Dogg Rap Hip Hop GIFs"></div>
```

I got some code from GitHub that already does so by finding all elements with the tag 'img':

```
def scrape_page():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    url = 'https://tenor.com/search/dance-gifs'
    print(f"Scrape: {url}")
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        print("Page is ready!")

        elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')[10:20]
        container_links = []
        for element in elements:
            container_links.append(element.get_attribute("src"))
```

However, this code also downloads the STICKERS section of the site (https://tenor.com/search/dance-gifs), whereas I want to only download the GIFs section.

I have tried multiple things without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the *`<img>`* only from the GIFs section you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://tenor.com/en-GB/search/dance-gifs')
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.Gif > img')
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://tenor.com/en-GB/search/dance-gifs')
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class='Gif ']/img')
  ```

Comment: Thank you! The CSS Selector code worked!